# Some bones do not move in pose mode

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

My problem is: I can't move SOME bones in Pose mode. If I try, it only rotates them.

*Yes, I know about "manipulate center points", sadly it did not help in my case. Enabled or disabled it does not make any difference at all.*

Here are 2 screenshots:

[image: bones in pose mode]
  I may easily move this and 3 other bones.

[image: bone only rotating]
This one turns dark orange and rotates, instead of dragging.

As you can see on these screenshots, both bones have exact proportions, same parent and no transfer limitations. Clearing/re-assigning parent bone does not help either. To be honest, I have no idea where else may I search for mistake. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible this might be related to auto-IK ; try going to the toolbar on the left of the screen, clicking on the options tab and turning off auto-IK.